# editing an object from the database

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a class extending Model, holding a short text and id. Objects are stored in a database.

My current problem is: Instead of replacing the old version of an object, a new one is created every time I try to edit an entry.

For me it looks as if the object is copied somewhen before saving?

I'd be very glad, if somebody could tell me how to avoid this! :-)

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Entry extends Model {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Required
public String   text;   
public String   studentName = "Hans";
@Id
public long     id;
public static   Finder<Long, Entry> finder = new Finder<Long, Entry>( Long.class, Entry.class);

public static Entry getMe(Long id) {
    return finder.byId(id);
}

public static List<Entry> getAll() {
    return finder.all();
}

public static void saveMe(Entry toDataBase) { 
    if(finder.byId(toDataBase.id)!=null)  // this seems to be always NULL 
    {
        System.out.println("update");
        toDataBase.update(); 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("save new");
        toDataBase.save();
    }
}
```

The controller part:

```
public static Result createReport(Long id) {
    if(Entry.getMe(id)==null)
        return ok(reports.render(form(Entry.class), Entry.getMe(id)));//Entry.class)));

    return ok(reports.render(entryForm.fill(Entry.getMe(id)),Entry.getMe(id)));//form(Entry.class), Entry.getMe(id)));//Entry.class)));
}
public static Result storeReport() {    
    Form<Entry> filledForm = entryForm.bindFromRequest();
    if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(error.render());
    } else {
        Entry.saveMe(filledForm.get());
        return ok(reports.render(filledForm, filledForm.get()));
    }
}
```

edit:
the html part:

```
@(entryForm: Form[Entry],e: Entry)
@import helper._
@main("report creation") {
<h1>report for Nils</h1>

    @form(routes.Application.storeReport()) {
        @textarea(entryForm("text"))
        <input type="submit" value="Store Report">
    }
    <br />
    <br />
    @(if(e!=null)e.getid())
    @form(routes.Application.listStuff()) {
        <input type="submit" value="Overview">
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a `Long` instead of a `long`. And use getters and setters instead of public fields.

Comment: thank you for the advice! unfortunately it still doesn't work :(
.. but you are right - getters and setters are cooler than public fields anyway ;)

Comment: Can you try defining the finder like `public static Finder<String, Product> find = new Finder<String, Product>(String.class, Product.class);` ?

Comment: I also prefer still using getters and setter. Did you changed the Long type for id: `public long     id;` If so try to `clean` then `run` your project. It was many times a saver for me when working with public props.

Comment: yes, I changed to long, also in the getters and setters. In the finder I can't - there it is still Long (.. not String, because I'd like to be able to have the same text multiple times in the database). I integrated the HTWL part into my post - probably the problem is located there? But anyway I think I am going to 'solve' the problem by implementing the project with a different framework :(  Thank you very much for your help! :)